Firebase Firestore Reads Optimization for Elective Selection for College (horrendous amount)
Our project revolves around an elective selection platform tailored for students within our department. During a specific window, typically from 7 PM to 12 AM, students have the opportunity to select their elective subjects. However, in our previous semester, we encountered a significant challenge with Firebase Firestore reads, despite having only around 120 participating students.
In response, we transitioned from the Spark plan to the Blaze plan and implemented a budget alert set at $1.2 or 100 Rs. Surprisingly, within just a few hours of the elective selection period, the budget alert was triggered, indicating an unexpectedly high volume of reads. Upon investigating further, we realized that even simple actions such as accessing the Firebase console and viewing changes and reads in Firestore contributed to the overall read count.
so I had to optimize it but I need help with it , the 2 problems I thought might contribute to sky high reads was
1 (major) me and my friend , we didnt kno just being on the firebase console website looking at the  changes and reads in the firestore would count as read too and that too a horrendous amount
2 (maybe ?) we implemented something like online / offline indicator feature for each students that gets registered
and we update  ( online : true ) after that user logins and update ( false) when they logout.
Last Time : we reached 25% of our budget in 6 hours for just 120 students
This time we have around 300 to 320 students and I want to make it optimized and be ready to kiss my money goodbye.
I need help in optimizing my code if anything is wrong with it or could be done better.Thank You!
Project Summary (Elective Table)
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useFirestore } from "../../hooks/useFirestore";
import { useLogout } from "../../hooks/useLogout";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import styles from "./ProjectSummary.module.css";

export default function ProjectSummary({ project }) {
  const { logout } = useLogout();
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  const [isEnrolled, setIsEnrolled] = useState(false);
  const [isConfirming, setIsConfirming] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleApprove = async () => {
    if (isEnrolled || isConfirming || isLoading) {
      return;
    }

    setIsConfirming(true);
    setIsLoading(true);

    const shouldEnroll = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to enroll?");

    setIsConfirming(false);

    if (shouldEnroll) {
      try {
        const firestore = firebase.firestore();
        const electiveRef = firestore.collection("electives").doc(project.id);
        const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

        const didEnroll = await firestore.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
          const electiveDoc = await transaction.get(electiveRef);
          if (!electiveDoc.exists) {
            throw new Error("Elective document does not exist!");
          }

          const electiveData = electiveDoc.data();
          if (electiveData.slots === 0) {
            return false;
          }

          transaction.update(electiveRef, {
            slots: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
          });

          await transaction.update(userRef, {
            isEnroll: true,
            elective: project.name,
            subjectCode: project.details,
          });

          return true;
        });

        if (didEnroll) {
          setIsEnrolled(true);
          logout();
        } else {
          alert("No available slots for enrollment.");
          setIsEnrolled(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error enrolling:", error);
        alert("An error occurred while enrolling. Please try again.");
        setIsEnrolled(false);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      setIsConfirming(false);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const [slots, setSlots] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSlots = async () => {
      try {
        const electiveDoc = await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("electives")
          .doc(project.id)
          .get();
        const electiveData = electiveDoc.data();
        setSlots(electiveData.slots);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching slots:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchSlots();
  }, [project.id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && (
        <div className={styles.overlay}>
          <div className={styles.loader}>Loading...</div>
        </div>
      )}
      <button
        className="btn"
        onClick={handleApprove}
        disabled={slots === 0 || isEnrolled || isLoading}
      >
        Enroll
      </button>

      {isEnrolled && (
        <div className={styles.overlay}>
          <div className="confirmation-box">
            <p>You have successfully enrolled</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


Pending.jsx (Elective page):
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection";
import { useDocument } from "../../hooks/useDocument";
import ProjectSummary from "../project/ProjectSummary";
import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext";

export default function Pending() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const { documents: electiveDocuments, error: electiveError } =
    useCollection("electives");
  const { document: userDocument, error: userError } = useDocument(
    "users",
    user.uid
  );
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserDocument = async () => {
      const { document, error } = await yourUserDocumentFetchingFunction(
        user.uid
      );

      if (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user document:", error);
        return;
      }

      setFilter(document?.department || "all");
    };

    fetchUserDocument();
  }, [user]);

  const yourUserDocumentFetchingFunction = async (uid) => {
    const response = await fetch(`your-api-endpoint/users/${uid}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return { document: data, error: null };
  };

  const projects = electiveDocuments
    ? electiveDocuments.filter((document) => {
        switch (filter) {
          case "all request":
            return true;
          default:
            return !document.assignedUsersList.some(
              (assignedUser) =>
                assignedUser?.uid.toLowerCase() ==
                userDocument?.department.toLowerCase()
            );
        }
      })
    : null;

  return true ? (
    <div className="pending-page">
      <h2 className="page-title">Electives </h2>
      {electiveError && <p className="error">{electiveError}</p>}
      {userError && <p className="error">{userError}</p>}
      <table className="project-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Elective Name</th>
            <th>Subject Code</th>
            <th>Click to Enroll</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {projects &&
            projects.map((project) => (
              <tr key={project.id}>
                <td className="td1">{project.name}</td>
                <td>{project.details}</td>
                <td>
                  <ProjectSummary project={project} />
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="signup-form">
      <h2>Chooser will open at 7PM</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

If you need some other part of my code to check , I will provide it .

Keeping the console web page open on an active collection will definitely incur a read for each document changed in that collection.  It's not a "free" service in that respect.  As far as other activity on your project - we can't see that and only you can measure it using whatever monitoring and metrics you apply to your own code.
